# Can Powershell tell the difference between Office 365 & Distribution groups?

Tags: powershell, office365

We have a lot of Distribution groups in Office 365 (ported from our old Lotus Notes system) and an increasing number of the new Office 365 groups.

Is there a cmdlet or code snippet in Powershell that could tell if a group is one or the other?

Depending on what kind of group it is, a function to list the members of a group needs to know whether to run either:

```
Get-UnifiedGroupLinks -Identity GroupName -LinkType Members

Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity GroupName | select Displayname
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way (that I am aware of) to query both types of groups. For instance, using `Get-DistributionGroup` will not return Office 365 groups. However, you can easily use that to your advantage.

I am not sure how your current script works, but if at any point you query your groups using both `Get-DistributionGroup` and `Get-UnifiedGroup`, and (assumedly) create an array of powershell objects, you can just attach an additional property that defines the type of group at that time, since you *know* groups returned by the appropriate command are of the command's type.

If you never do this, and are only using the group name, there is no way to define the type of group *before* querying o365 in some way. Sadly the only real way to tell which one will work is to simply use a `try {x -ErrorAction Stop} catch {}`, since each command will throw an error when querying a group not of their types.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give the array idea a try.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use Get-Recipient.

On a Distribution List the RecipientTypeDetails is MailUniversalDistributionGroup but on an Office 365 Group the RecipientTypeDetails is GroupMailbox

Comment: please contextualize more your answer, show a code example etc